# Does a corporation pay same capital gains tax as an individual?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, canada, capital-gain

If I open up a corporation in Canada and the sole purpose of the corporation is to trade stocks, does the corporation pay the same kind of taxes on investment gains as if I were trading those stocks as an individual?

Usually corporation income tax is lower than individual tax, but I know this is true for income tax, while I am not sure about investment taxes.

Comment: The corporate income tax rate is in the high 30s, which is similar to the individual rate at the amount of income we're talking about (higher actually, when you take into account that corporate rate structures aren't progressive, so the corporation pays 39 cents on its first dollar while the individual pays nada); the big difference in the "effective" rate is that individuals basically pay taxes on *revenue* (income before expenses, with just a few exceptions), while corporations pay taxes on *profits* (income after expenses, with a lot more able to be called an "expense").

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_gains_tax#Canada):

> For corporations as for individuals, only 50% of realized capital
>   gains are taxable.

Thus, it would appear to be the same though there is something to be said for special cases as TFSAs and RRSPs could get different tax treatment from a regular account.

Comment: Don't forget that you'll pay tax when withdrawing the money from the corporation, too.